# Design pattern for setAnimated and IBInspectable property in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I can’t figure out how to incorporate a design pattern in to my Swift class which has a property with the following requirements:

- Property with default value and is IBInspectable
- accompanying `setProperty:animated:` method

All of the ways I’ve tried require a separate private ‘instance' variable e.g. _property, like below:

```
@IBInspectable var progress: CGFloat = 0.5 {
    didSet {
        _progress = progress

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

private var _progress: CGFloat = 0.5

func setProgress(progress: CGFloat, animated: Bool)
{
    if _progress == progress
    {
        return
    }

    if animated
    {
        //  Animate changes

        //  [Animation code]
    }
    else
    {
        //  No need to animate changes

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    titleLabel?.text = "\(NSInteger(progress * 100))%"

    //  Update value

    _progress = progress
}
```

This doesn’t account for getting the property value though. As a property cannot have a `get` and `didSet` method.

So what is the correct way of having a property which is `IBInspectable` and can be set in the setAnimated method without automatically updating, bypassing the animation?